MATLAB: Trouble Using printpreview
I've got an image I'd like to print on letter paper with a width of 25.4 cm, and a height of 21.2 cm (the 2D array is 212 x 254 elements, so I'd like each element to take up a millimeter of space on printed paper). I'm using the printpreview function to take a look at the image before I print it, and the Layout and Paper sections seem to have the specifications I'm looking for, but the image does not appear to be the size I'd like it to be (the image should take up ~90% of the paper, but it doesn't). To overexaggerate, I changed the figure dimensions to be something larger than the size of the paper itself, but the software seems to be handling it just fine. What should I do so that the image fits the dimensions I specify?
Here's my code:
clear
clc
close all

x = 27.94;
y = 21.59;
xmarg = (27.94 - 25.4)/2;  
ymarg = (21.59 - 21.2)/2;
xsize = 25.4;
ysize = 21.2;

metaData = niftiinfo('index_image.nii');
vol = niftiread(metaData);

[volProc] = preProcessBrainCANDIData(vol, metaData, true);

[saggital, coronal, transverse] = size(volProc);
slice = volProc(:, :, transverse / 2);

sliceViewer(vol)

bfig = figure;
imagesc(slice)
axis off;
colormap(gray) 

clim([0, 255]);

set(bfig, 'Units','centimeters', 'Position',[0 0 xsize ysize])
movegui(bfig, 'center')

set(bfig, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
set(bfig, 'PaperPosition',[xmarg ymarg xsize ysize])
set(bfig, 'PaperOrientation', 'landscape');

printpreview`

I've also just tried hard coding in the size of the figure, to no avail.

Hi Bell, I couldn't reproduce this code; we can help better if you include an example slice

@Zain hi! All that niftiinfo and niftiread stuff is brain imaging jargon. volProc is a 3D array (it's a brain represented by a 3D array), and slice is variable that stores, quite literally, à slice I've taken of volProc, so it represents a 2D array. For purposes of recreation, you could just initialize a 212 x 254 array and fill it with random values (or make it all one value, even).

This is likely a setting in the printer driver (check your system’s printer configuration panel). Nowadays printers tend to scale the image you print so it fits on the paper.

Try the following code,
clear
clc
close all

x = 27.94;
y = 21.59;
xmarg = (27.94 - 25.4)/2;  
ymarg = (21.59 - 21.2)/2;
xsize = 25.4;
ysize = 21.2;

% random slice per your suggestion!

slice = randi(255, 212,254);

% set boundaries to 200 to make them visible
slice(:, 1:5)=200;
slice(:, end-5:end)=200;    
slice(1:5,:)=200;
slice(end-5:end, :)=200;

bfig = figure;
imagesc(slice)
axis off;
colormap(gray) 

clim([0, 255]);

set(bfig, 'Units','centimeters', 'Position',[0 0 xsize ysize])
movegui(bfig, 'center')

set(bfig, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
set(bfig, 'PaperPosition',[xmarg ymarg xsize ysize])
set(bfig, 'PaperOrientation', 'landscape');

% Added material
ax = gca;
outerpos = ax.OuterPosition;
ti = ax.TightInset; 
left = outerpos(1) + ti(1);
bottom = outerpos(2) + ti(2);
ax_width = outerpos(3) - ti(1) - ti(3);
ax_height = outerpos(4) - ti(2) - ti(4);
ax.Position = [left bottom ax_width ax_height];


printpreview

This gives me the following result,

you can modify ax.Position margins to get your desired result.

Could you explain what you did, by any chance?

This code is a general case with possible titles and axis labels, in your case you could ignore my additions and just add  'ax = gca;
ax.Units= "centimeters";
ax.Position = [0 0 xsize ysize];' which modifies the ax handle position instead of the whole image which involves boundaries and margins as well.

Oh, so were the additional labels and the axes and such taking up extra space, I just couldn't see them since I have axes hidden, and what you did essentially was sort redefine the boundaries of the axes such that they no longer took up extra space?

yes, you're right, fig takes more space than the axes alone.

Sure, it's rare for bioscience people to work with Matlab :) Your question was well presented.
